# Minimizing the time consumption of SQL Query among large data

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Here I 'm running the below query in Azure SQL using the BI tool to fetch data from a large volume.The BI tool shows the below error `The query exceeded the maximum allowable time of execution time of 10 seconds` on the below query :

```
SELECT M + ' ' +Convert(varchar,CY) TimeSpan,
       ISNULL(SUM([Australia]), 0) AS [Australia],
       ISNULL(SUM([India]), 0) AS [India],
       ISNULL(SUM([America]), 0) AS [America]
       FROM (
                select Distinct DeviceID,RegionName, Month(LastCommunicated) CM, Year(LastCommunicated) CY, 1 Cnt
                ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,LastCommunicated),3) M
                from Region
                WHERE LastCommunicated BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) and dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
             ) a 
               PIVOT (Sum(Cnt) FOR RegionName IN ([Australia],[India],[America])) AS Result
       GROUP BY CY,CM,M + ' ' +Convert(varchar,CY)
        ORDER BY CY,CM
```

Is there any alternative way to fix this issue instead of increasing the execution time in BI ?

Comment: We'd need to see an execution plan of the query. Otherwise it would be just guessing.

Comment: Would the subquery table "a" do better with a Group by Month instead of the distinct LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,LastCommunicated),3)    The difference between number of comunications vs the length or total minutes of comunication is probably important to you and may be why you would do the "a" subquery one way or the other.